# What is causing the Rendering Problems : Couldn't resolve resource error in Android Studio 1.1.0?

Tags: android, resources, rendering

I was looking into the Android Studio, and was trying out some basic app development.
The learning material I was using is based on an older version of Android Studio which is still in beta stage, and I wanted to check out the latest version, 1.1.0.
In version 1.1.0, I run into an error when trying to change the preview engine to versions below 17(such as api 14)

> Rendering Problems
>   Couldn't resolve resource
>   @style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode
>   (2 similar errors not shown)

This happens from the very beginning of the project, in the "Hello World" template. What is the cause of this problem, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Do you mean to put `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode`? (_Action_ not Actoin)

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for pointing out. Made a correction just now

Comment: You can check my answer below, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am having the same problem below API 19 in the preview. Do not worry about it, select your API 19 or above and the problem will disappear.

It is only the preview, so it doesn't matter. However, ensure that it is working on all platforms on an android device (like an emulator or a real device).