# Changing action bar color in android studio

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

Im trying to change my action bar color so i created this style

```
<style name="trial" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#3BB9FF</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle"   parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000080</item>
</style>
```

but it's not working 
i have this error  :   Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode

but in the layout preview it's working fine [image: like this]

Comment: If you aren't far gone in your project, I'd suggest to use a [Toolbar](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html) instead.Same thing with much fewer issues when used with AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu i fnd that helpful but i already gone so far with my project. I just want to change the background color of the action bar but no matter how hard i tried i still have the same rendering error : Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode

Comment: In that case, go to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771082/android-couldnt-resolve-resource-style-widget-holo-light-actionmode-inverse) link and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655929/what-is-causing-the-rendering-problems-couldnt-resolve-resource-error-in-andr)  to see if any of the answers help.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu i already saw them and tried them but still the same error appears

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code under /res/values/styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleBarTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF1D3F7A</item>
</style>

<style name="TitleBarTextColor" parent="@style/MyActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

`FF1D3F7A` being the background color

Comment: it has the same rendering error : Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode